Add Variable Django Form without Putting in Field
I am trying to add a variable to a Django form, without the variable being a field on the form. I want a set of checkboxes that are checked if the user is subscribed. When the form is loaded, the options are not loaded successfully. All subscriptions are checked when the form loads. The update function works appropriately and the database reflects the correct selections after submission. Please help me figure out why the appropriate usersubscriptions are not checked when the form loads.
models.py
class Subscription(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class UserSubscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " " + self.subscription.name

views.py
@login_required(login_url='login')
def managesubscription(request):
    userSubscriptions = UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    subscriptions = Subscription.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ManageSubscriptionForm(request.POST, userSubscriptions=userSubscriptions)
        if form.is_valid():
            subscriptions = form.cleaned_data['subscriptions']
            UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=request.user).delete()
            for subscription in subscriptions:
                print(subscription)
                UserSubscription.objects.create(user=request.user, subscription=subscription)
            messages.info(request, 'Subscriptions Updated')
            return redirect('dashboard')
    form = ManageSubscriptionForm(userSubscriptions=userSubscriptions, initial={'subscriptions': subscriptions, 'userSubscriptions': userSubscriptions})
    return render(request, 'account/managesubscriptions.html', {'form': form})

forms.py
class ManageSubscriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subscriptions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Subscription.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),   
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, userSubscriptions, **kwargs):
        self.userSubscriptions = userSubscriptions
        print("here", userSubscriptions)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = ['subscriptions']

managesubscriptions.html
<body>
    <br>
    <div class="container bg-white shadow-md p-5 form-layout">
        <h3>Update Subscriptions</h3>
        {% csrf_token %}

        <br><br>
        <form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for subscription in form.subscriptions %}
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="subscriptions" value="{{ subscription.id }}" id="subscription{{ subscription.id }}" 
                    {% if subscription.id in userSubscriptions %} checked {% endif %}> {{ subscription }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <br />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Update Subscriptions</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>


to start with, you need to filter user_subscriptions by retrieving only the subscriptions for which the user is already registered
 usersubscriptions = UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('subscription_id', flat=True)

values_list is a Django method that allows you to retrieve only certain fields from a queryset, rather than the whole object. It retrieves only the subscription_id field of each UserSubscription found by the previous filter.
flat=True indicates that the result must be a simple list of values, not a list of tuples.
Without flat=True, the result would be tuples containing a single element each (e.g. [(1,), (2,), (3,)]).
With flat=True, you get a flat list like [1, 2, 3]. Retrieves the subscriptions selected in the form
selected_subscriptions = form.cleaned_data['subscriptions']
selected_subscription_ids = set(sub.id for sub in selected_subscriptions)

selected_subscription_ids creates a set containing the unique IDs of the subscriptions selected by the user.
sub.id for sub in selected_subscriptions comes from Python. Basically, it scans each Subscription object in selected_subscriptions and retrieves its id attribute.
et le set permet de transformer la séquence d’IDs en un ensemble
Only deletes subscriptions that have been unchecked
UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=request.user).exclude(subscription_id__in=selected_subscription_ids).delete()

Defines the subscriptions initially selected
form = ManageSubscriptionForm(userSubscriptions=userSubscriptions, initial={'subscriptions': usersubscriptions})

in forms.py For the init method:
def __init__(self, *args, subscriptions=None, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if subscriptions is not None:
        self.fields['subscriptions'].queryset = subscriptions

super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)calls the constructor of the parent class (forms.ModelForm). This initializes the form normally, processing all the arguments and keywords passed when the form instance was created.
subscriptions will allow a specific queryset to be passed for the subscriptions field during initialisation.
if subscriptions is not None i.e. if subscriptions is provided, the queryset of self.fields['subscriptions'] is replaced by this specific queryset. This means that only Subscription instances specified in this queryset will be displayed in the form.

Thank you so much for your suggestions, as well as the detailed explanation of why to utilize the code. This helps immensely. Currently, this works if there is at least one subscription checked. If there are no subscriptions checked, the unselected options are not deleted.
     UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=request.user).exclude(subscription_id__in=selected_subscription_ids).delete()


I'm glad this helps
To handle this case you just need to make a condition to check if selected_subscription_ids is empty if it is you just need to do UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=user).delete()

I had to move this to the else of if form.valid(). Thank you so much for your help!
